# ligtning-input date showing junk numbers in years

Tags: lightning-web-components, force.com-sites, digital-experience

In my digital experience site I made one date control in LWC as with the code below

```
     <lightning-input type="date" required name="dob"  label="Date Of Birth" onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
```

When I render this in community in year column its showing some junk characters but inside normal salesforce its not showing this junk charecter.
This is happening in both MAC and Windows machine.

[image]

[image]
Here is the guest user locale settings

[image]

Comment: It seems like a japanese locale is set for the community user.

Comment: What is the template being used?  Is the behavior the same across all templates like customer service / Build your own (LWR) etc? Thanks

Comment: @Swetha We are using Build your own (LWR)

Comment: I was able to repro this behavior in my org. I tested with customer service and Build your own (LWR) templates and it happens only on LWR template. I'll check with our concerned Salesforce Product team to confirm if this is a bug and update this thread. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The additional labels beside the year is related to the [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001wCxEQAU&title=japanese-imperial-calendar-showing-in-byo-template) wherein the "lightning-input type=date" is by default picking the Japanese Imperial Calendar even though the setting is disabled.

The workaround would be to use html input element instead of lightning-input-field

ETA for the fix for this known issue is WINTER '23(Safe Harbor)